# integrating YAF.NET in my MVC3 Razor Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, yaf

I would like to know if there is a way to integrate [YAF.NET](http://yetanotherforum.net/) to my MVC3 Application?

I dont want YAF to be inside my page like using my masterpage or stuff like that, I just want it to be in a subfolder like `/forum` and if a user clicks the *"forum"* link he will be redirected to the forum.

In the future I also would like to use a login system for my page, so I have to think about membership provider. I know that there is a way to make YAF use your basic asp.net membership provider but will yaf work with mvc 3 in that way? Since yaf isn't a .NET 4 application I wonder how I could migrate the membership provider?

If there isn't a solution for the membership stuff, I should be able to just link from my page to YAF?

EDIT:

My solution ->

1)I added a subdomain and config both of mine domains to use an A-Record which points to the Server where IIS is running.

2)I added 2 Websites. The first one is my Main Website with my MVC3 Application and the second one is the [YAF.NET](http://yetanotherforum.net/) Forum.

3) I edited the binding settings of both of the websites (IIS Manager -> Sites -> yoursite -> Binding) and removed the IP binding insteed i added a HTTP header. For mainsite = mydomain.com and for the forum forum.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you can just install YAF in a virtual directory on your website like `www.mywebsite.com/forums/` and let it run standalone there.

1. Create a new Virtual Directory in the folder you like. (`/forums`)
2. Set permissions, .NET settings etc accordingly and install YAF there.

For the second, what you could do is use from your MVC app, directly read YAF's database of users (wherever it is) and use it to authenticate your users.

The Latest build of [YAF](http://yetanotherforum.net/) is on ASP.net 3.5, you could try getting the source and building it for .NET4, although this would not be necessary since you said you don't want to mash your app with it but run it side-by-side and have them interop. (There also is some UserControl feature for CMS's you might want to check that out)

On the [features](http://yetanotherforum.net/features.aspx) page it says YAF supports asp.net memberships and roles, so you shouldn't have a problem there either.

Comment: Your welcome, also, would be nice if you posted an update in your question once you finished doing this.

Comment: i created a virtual directory called "forum" in the IIS Manager under my already existing web site and put all the yaf files there.. now he says " 
 
A section, as allowDefinition = 'Is MachineToApplication' is registered on the program level to use causes an error. This error can be caused by a virtual directory that is configured as an application in IIS."  do i have to convert this virtual directory to an application?

Comment: sorry it's translated by bing translator :p

Comment: Make sure the Version of .NET is set to .NET2 on the directory.  Make sure you have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on your machine.

Comment: ok i agree the problem is, that i set my Application Pool targeting to .NET 4 .. but i can only change the AppPool of a site or of an application.. but if i create a virtual directory under my default website.. this directory will be targeting .NET 4, because my main website needs it to be .NET 4